# Is 10% "a fraction" or "a small fraction"?

Tags: word-meaning, usage, redundancy

I would like to know if I should refer to something that is **1/10 or 10%** of something else as **a fraction of** or **a small fraction of** that something else.

According to the definitions of fraction, fraction refers to a small or tiny proportion of something, so, from that perspective, adding "small" would maybe be necessary or unnecessary (I don't know) for 1/10 or 10%. Maybe, a small fraction would be something like 1/100 or 1%, but not 1/10 or 10%. However, I also feel that adding "small" emphasizes that it's not a big fraction (say 4/10 or 40%).

Note that I am not specifying that 1/10 or 10% figure anywhere in my text.

Comment: If you were hoping to sell something for £100 and someone offered you more than £90 or less than £10 you probably *wouldn't* say *That's just a fraction of what I was expecting*. But you *might* - exactly what range of values can be called "a fraction" in conversational English is subject to the whim of the speaker and context. And the same applies to adjectivally modified versions such as a ***small / tiny / substantial** fraction*.

Comment: Please cite the definitions you're using. 9/10 is undeniably a fraction but represents what I think nearly everyone would consider to be a large proportion of a whole.

Comment: You are conflating [two different meanings of "fraction"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fraction). *She paid a fraction of the price I paid.* is the "small" or "little" meaning. *The answer to the math question was 3/8 of Y.* is the "a numerical representation (such as ³/₄, ⁵/₈, or 3.234) indicating the quotient of two numbers" meaning.

Comment: It is entirely dependent on context and what you mean... Is a cat a "small" animal?  It is big compared to mice, but small compared to elephants.....  10% is big compared to 1% but small compared to 90%.  There is no correct answer to this question so I've voted to close.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to know if I should refer to something that is 1/10 or
> 10% of something else as a fraction of or a small fraction of that
> something else. ... Note that I am not specifying that 1/10 or 10%
> figure anywhere in my text.

There is no absolute numerical measure for words like "small", "large" etc.  A small elephant is much bigger than a large mouse.

If you know the percentage then state it - if you don't then you must use your own judgement relative to the situation you are discussing.

As mentioned by ColleenV in the comments, there is a difference between a mathematical fraction (for example 9/10 or 90%) and the everyday usage which refers to "a small amount".

Answer (score 1):

As currently worded, this question could just boil down to using or not using an emphasis ("small"). *It depends, nevertheless, on the actual context*: what were you trying to imply, or what you would like to emphasize (and whether you're trying to emphasize on it at all).

To address the emphasis with "small": quite often when speaking any language you're using words that are supposed to make emphasis without altering the meaning of the phrase you say: for example, I can omit "quite" in this very sentence, and I can omit "very" in the phrase you've just read, neither of that changes meaning significantly.

Such an emphasis makes the text feel either natural, or versatile, or just generally better expresses your thoughts.

**However!** Chances are high that you're *not likely to choose between just a fraction and a small fraction*, but have way more descriptions in that list. The first question you should answer is: is 10% too much for your case or it can be neglected? Does these 10% matter a lot or it does not?

Consider the following examples:

> In only a couple of days, I was able to do most of work and have only 10% left

"A small fraction" is a phrase you can use to describe this. The thing is, if in that context you had a difficult task to do, and you've ripped through the first 90% that fast, you can say that you don't have much to do left, probably a only couple of hours will be enough to complete everything. You can say: "*I have done 90% of my job with only just a fraction left*" or "*I have done 90% of my job with only a small fraction left*".

> This investment has resulted in steady 10% of annual profit, adjusted for inflation, that's a reasonable profit.

This depends on what you consider a good investment, but 10% is *not bad* for something that doesn't involve high risks. You don't want to call it a small fraction here, not even a fraction: 10% is quite substantive here.

> Only 10% of students do regularly attend this class.

Again, a small fraction is relevant here: this is *some really non-exemplary* attendance rate. 10% is totally not a lot here, but rather really few.

> This system has a false-positive rate of 10%.

10% is *a lot* in this case! You may want to desribe it as a "this system with a significantly high margin of error", but definitely not a small fraction. For example, 1% of false positives vs 10% would produce 10 times less tasks that have to be handled, so 10% is really not something you'd want to call "a small fraction" here.

Answer (score -2):

A percentage is a **proportion**. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/proportion) has

> **proportion**
> the number or amount of a group or part of something when compared to the whole
> *The report shows that poor families spend a larger proportion of their income on food.*

You don't give an actual usage example but could say

> I give a small proportion of my income to charity.